# Tomcat Server Netbeans 8.0 is not working in Windows 8

Tags: tomcat, cordova, netbeans

After creating a new java Web Application Project in net beans,When i am trying to deploy it in Tomcat

Server( apache-tomcat-7.0.53-windows-x64 ) getting below error,can any one please help me

out,Thanks in Advance.

> ant -f
>   \NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1
>   -Dbrowser.context=Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1
>   -DforceRedeploy=false -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run init: deps-module-jar: deps-ear-jar: deps-jar: library-inclusion-in-archive:
>   library-inclusion-in-manifest: compile: compile-jsps: Starting Tomcat
>   process... Waiting for Tomcat... Tomcat server started. In-place
>   deployment at
>   ...\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\build\web
>   Deployment is in progress...
>   deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FTHULAS%7E1%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext3096225649611752059.xml&path=/WebApplication1
>   Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:
>   xxxx:8080/manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FTHULAS%7E1%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext3096225649611752059.xml&path=/WebApplication1
>   ...\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045:
>   The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 23 seconds)

Comment: Are you on a network that uses any sort of proxy configuration? In Netbeans options, could you select to use the "No Proxy" option and try deploy/run your app again?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I just ran into the same thing and since I couldn't find an answer, here is what I did to get it to work:

1) Set up the `%Catalina Home%/conf/tomcat-users.xml` file with something like this:

```
<role rolename="ide"/>
<user password="secret" roles="manager-script" username="ide"/>
```

Where `ide` is the username and `secret` the password used in the server configuration in Netbeans.

[image: Netbeans Tomcat config]

2) Set JAVA_HOME and/or JRE_HOME environment variables in Windows

[image]

3) **Run** Netbeans **as Administrator**. There might be a way around this, but this works for me. If not run as Administrator the Tomcat startup.bat will be run as a restricted user which results in no permission to write log files etc. and then fails to deploy the webapp.